# How to make transactions concurrent

Tags: spring, concurrency, transactions

So, I have a concurrent application that I am building using Scala, Akka and Spring.
I create writer actors and to each pass a chunk of data. This chunk of data belongs to 3 different classes. Hence, 3 different tables. There are parent-child relations between these 3 classes. So, the processing and insertion has to happen serially. Further there is a requirement that the whole chunk is inserted or none at all. Hence, the need for a transaction

Essentially from my writer, I call an insert method described as below.

```
@Transactional
insert(){
    repo.save(obj1)
    repo.save(obj2)
    repo.batchSave(List(obj3))
}
```

This happens from all my writers. Without the @Transactional, the system is highly concurrent and fast. However with it, it is becoming serialized. That is,all my chunks are written one after the other, thus destroying all my concurrency.So, what am I missing if any, or is this a mandatory trade-off meaning is it not possible to have both transactions and concurrency.

Also, a very basic doubt about transactions.
Lets's say there are 2 transactions, T1 and T2

```
T1
begin
insert1
insert2
insert3
commit

T2
begin
insert4
insert5
insert6
commit
```

If I have 2 transactions as above with insert as the only operation. Will it be parallelized or will it be serialized? Is there anything like once T1 begins, will it release locks only after commit? How can this be parallelized? Because all isolation levels talk about is a read and write happening parallely and hence the case for dirty reads and READ_UNCOMMITTED.

Additional details:

- Sybase relational DB
- SpringJDBC jdbcTemplate for inserts
- Isolation levels:Tried default and READ_UNCOMMITTED

Any guidance or ideas would be immensely helpful. Thanks

Comment: There is no easy answer it depends on isolation levels, database you are using, persistence technology used etc. imho there is too little information to give an informed answer.

Comment: @M.Deinum, yea my bad. Using Spring JDBC for inserts with jdbcTemplate. Isolation level, I have set it to READ_UNCOMMITTED since it's the lowest possible. And its a Sybase DB.